# HTML trying to stylize table header

Tags: html

Here is my current code for my table. I am trying to make the table header "Famous Monsters by Birth Year" the color red and cannot figure out for the life of me how to do it.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Table Time</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Famous Monsters by Birth Year</th>
            </tr>
            <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid black;">
                <th style="padding:5px;"><em>Famous Monster</em></th>
                <th style="padding:5px;border-left:1px solid black;"><em>Birth Year</em></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:5px;">King Kong</td>
                <td style="padding:5px;border-left:1px solid black;">1933</td>     
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="padding:5px;">Dracula</td>
                <td style="padding:5px;border-left:1px solid black;">1897</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="padding:5px;">Bride of Frankenstein</td>
                <td style="padding:5px;border-left:1px solid black;">1944</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use a separate CSS file and simply want to make the header red within your html you can do the following:

```
<th colspan="2"><font color="red">Famous  by Birth Year</font></th>
```

But as the collor attribute of the `font` tag is not supported by HTML5 I would recommend using in-line CSS:

```
 <th colspan="2" style="color:red">Famous  by Birth Year</th>
```

Comment: No problem, be sure to check out my update with the better option.